# Yandex-Tank unable to run JMeter - Unable to access to JMeter executable file or it does not exist

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, yandex-tank, yandexcloud

I'm trying to start `JMeter` from `Yandex.Tank` in Yandex Cloud instance, based on Ubuntu 18.
Installed JMeter here: `/home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter`
If I run JMeter using this path it starts successfully:
`/home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter -n -t ReloadTest.jmx -l result-1.jtl -e -o ./result-1`

When I run `yandex-tank`, there is an error message:

```
[ERROR] Test interrupted:
<type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: Unable to access to JMeter executable file or it does not exist: 
/home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter
```

load.yaml:

```
phantom:
  enabled: false
jmeter:
  enabled: true
  jmx: ReloadTest.jmx
  buffered_seconds: 10
  jmeter_path: /home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter
  jmeter_ver: 5.2
  ext_log: all
overload:
  enabled: true
  package: yandextank.plugins.DataUploader
  token_file: "token.txt"
```

Tried this, without success:

```
chmod +x /home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter
chmod 777 /home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using latest YandexTank 1.12.8.1, you might want to update your current installation using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) like:

```
pip install https://api.github.com/repos/yandex/yandex-tank/tarball/master
```

If will still be experiencing problems - run YandexTank with `-v` command-line argument, it should produce more verbose debug messages so you will be able to figure out where the problem lives

```
2020-03-16 09:45:38,960 [DEBUG] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:267        Starting <yandextank.plugins.JMeter.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d57a090>
2020-03-16 09:45:38,968 [INFO] yandextank.plugins.JMeter.plugin plugin.py:119   Starting /home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter with arguments: ['/home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/jmeter', '-n', '-t', '/modified_s7ZsHU.jmx', '-j', '/logs/2020-03-16_09-45-22.748390/jmeter_0vPrFi.log', '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.default_delimiter=\\t', '-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true']
2020-03-16 09:45:50,632 [WARNING] yandextank.plugins.JMeter.plugin plugin.py:188        JMeter UDP port wasn't discovered
2020-03-16 09:45:50,635 [INFO] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:271 Plugin <yandextank.plugins.JMeter.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d57a090> required 11.666250 seconds to start
2020-03-16 09:45:50,637 [DEBUG] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:267        Starting <yandextank.plugins.RCAssert.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d5059d0>
2020-03-16 09:45:50,640 [INFO] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:271 Plugin <yandextank.plugins.RCAssert.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d5059d0> required 0.000021 seconds to start
2020-03-16 09:45:50,647 [DEBUG] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:267        Starting <yandextank.plugins.Telegraf.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d505110>
2020-03-16 09:45:50,650 [DEBUG] yandextank.plugins.Telegraf.plugin plugin.py:62 load_start_time = 1584351950.65
2020-03-16 09:45:50,655 [INFO] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:271 Plugin <yandextank.plugins.Telegraf.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d505110> required 0.005424 seconds to start
2020-03-16 09:45:50,659 [DEBUG] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:267        Starting <yandextank.plugins.ResourceCheck.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d505c50>
2020-03-16 09:45:50,664 [INFO] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:271 Plugin <yandextank.plugins.ResourceCheck.plugin.Plugin object at 0x7fe01d505c50> required 0.000014 seconds to start
2020-03-16 09:45:50,666 [INFO] yandextank.core.tankcore tankcore.py:279 Waiting for test to finish...
```

You can also try to [change the ownership of the whole JMeter folder](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) to the `tank` user like:

```
chown -R tank /home/tank/apache-jmeter-5.2.1
```

And finally, you can consider switching to [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool which better supports JMeter and is capable of [automatically downloading JMeter with plugins](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Location-Auto-Installation) so you won't have to worry about installing JMeter. Check out [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/) article for more details.